# How to convert CosmosDB FeedIterator result to IAsyncEnumerable or IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

It's a bit tricky to get data from CosmosDb FeedIterator converted into IEnumerable in a simple reusable way without having to write loops and iteration all over the place.

The [official Microsoft example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.container.getitemlinqqueryable?view=azure-dotnet) which is not as neat as I like it looks like this:

```
using (FeedIterator setIterator = container.GetItemLinqQueryable<Book>()
                     .Where(b => b.Title == "War and Peace")
                     .ToFeedIterator())
{                   
    //Asynchronous query execution
    while (setIterator.HasMoreResults)
    {
        foreach(var item in await setIterator.ReadNextAsync())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Price); 
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like to have a reusable oneliner and didn't find one, so I wrote one.

Especially when it's to be used in a .NET API so I wrote an extension method to convert the FeedIterator to IAsyncEnumerable that you can use the

(In C# 8 you can return IAsyncEnumerable from your API but if you need compatibility with netstandard2.0 as I do you can convert the IAsyncEnumerable to a regular IEnumerable)

Comment: I believe this is in the v4 branch of the SDK: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/issues/903

Comment: Oh! Nice. I didn't know. Thank you!

Answer (score 19):

This is how I solved it:

**Extension method:**

```
public static class CosmosDbExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Convert a feed iterator to IAsyncEnumerable
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TModel"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="setIterator"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static async IAsyncEnumerable<TModel> ToAsyncEnumerable<TModel>(this FeedIterator<TModel> setIterator)
    {
        while (setIterator.HasMoreResults)
            foreach (var item in await setIterator.ReadNextAsync())
            {
                yield return item;
            }
    }
}
```

**To return IAsyncEnumerable:**

```
 public virtual IAsyncEnumerable<TModel> Query()
    {
        Container container = GetContainer(); // Your code to get container 

        return  container.GetItemLinqQueryable<TModel>().ToFeedIterator().ToAsyncEnumerable();
    }
```

**To return IEnumerable:**

```
public virtual async Task<IEnumerable<TModel>> Query()
{

    Container container = GetContainer(); // Your code to get container 

    using (var feedIterator = container.GetItemLinqQueryable<TModel>().ToFeedIterator())
    {
        return await feedIterator.ToAsyncEnumerable().ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

(More about .ToListAsync() from the System.Linq.Async package in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59380538/348841))

Comment: Hi, I noticed that one time I do something like await myQuery.CountAsync() after using ToAsyncEnumerable(), I can't execute it a seconde time because of the feedOperator has been already read, is there a way to reset it each time I call something like myQuery.CountAsync()/.ToListAsync() ... etc ?