Falcon.NET doesn't find interfaces that are definitely there
I'm using the Falcon.NET KNX library (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Knx.Falcon.Sdk/) for connecting to KNX IP endpoints on my network. They are two of them, they work fine and respond in Tunneling mode (they do not work in Routing mode).
The code I use to construct a connection is similar to the following:
var options = new IpTunnelingConnectorParameters("192.168.30.5");

My problem is when it comes to enumerating all the IP endpoints. I use IpDeviceDiscovery.DiscoverAsync(). As soon as I invoke it, I can see through Wireshark that correct requests and responses go via port 3761 (UDP). Everything works, and yet when I call
var ipDiscovery = new IpDeviceDiscovery
{
  Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)
};
var ipDeviceDiscoveryTask = ipDiscovery.DiscoverAsync(cancel);
var result = await ipDeviceDiscoveryTask.ToArray();

the result variable has 0 elements.
Now, here is the problem: I tried decompiling DiscoverAsync but it's obfuscated (not to mention being async, so I cannot determine exactly what the problem is. I know the interfaces are there, I use them just fine, but for some unknown reason it's not returning them as an enumeration. Which is annoying.

what does DiscoverAsync return and why is there no await ?

@IvanPetrov fixed

and what extension method on the returend IAsyncEnumerable do you use for the ToArray() ?

Does ETS discover the two tunneling interfaces, i.e. do they show up in the connection menu?

@KlausGütter yes

Do you use the newest Falcon version (6.3.7959)? Does extending the Timeout make any difference? Which .NET version do you use? Is this a Console or a GUI App?

@KlausGütter latest version, timeout extension - tried, did no help, .NET 9, console app

Can you please provide a complete [mre] showing the problem?

Just tested it again and it works fine for me. I don't know however what this ToArray() extension method is that you seem to use.

DiscoverAsync returns IAsyncEnumerable<IpDeviceDiscoveryResult>.
To enumerate the discovered IP devices, use
await foreach (var ipDiscoveryResult in ipDiscovery.DiscoverAsync(cancel))
{
    // You will get here whenever a SearchResponse arrives.
    // Do whatever you like with ipDiscoveryResult.
}

If you just want the final results as a list, you could use ToListAsync() extension method from System.Linq.Async. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/59380538/2142950 for an example.
